# How to use Moq on singleton classes so that we can only test Business logic and ignore logging

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, singleton, moq

```
 public class SLogger
 {
     private const string SSchemasFileName = "sSchemas";
     private const string SLogsFileName = "sLogs";

     private static string logsDir = @"D:\Data\logs\local\";
     private static readonly Lazy<SLogger> instance = new Lazy<SLogger>(() => new SLogger());

     private ESC eSC;
     private AEL aEL;

     private SllLogger()
     {
         eSC= new ESC(logsDir , SSchemasFileName);
         aEL= new AEL(logsDir , SLogsFileName, EventLevel.Verbose);
     }

     public static SLogger Instance
     {
         get
         {
             return instance.Value;
         }
     }

     public void LogInformation()
     {
         // Some logic here
     }
}
```

How can I use Moq framework to just test the business logic and ignore the logging library code?

For example if I have some class which has a method as shown below and I want to unit test this method using Moq framework or any other framework then how can I Moq this singleton class?

Is there any other way I can do it?

```
void foo()
{
   // Business logic

   SLogger.Instance.LogInformation();

   // Business logic
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without having an abstraction to depend on instead of a tight coupling to `SLogger`, there's no way to test `foo()` independently.

I'd suggest you define an interface for `SLogger` to implement; minimally, given your example:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogInformation();
}
```

I'd further suggest you provide an instance of `ILogger` in your class' constructor, as a form of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and have your class invoke methods of the injected dependency:

```
public class Bar
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Bar(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation();
    }
}
```

From your calling code, you can now provide a real implementation of `ILogger`, be it a singleton instance of `SLogger`, or a mock for a unit test:

```
//Real call
var myBar = new Bar(SLogger.Instance);

//From a test
var testBar = new Bar(new Mock<ILogger>().Object);
```

There are plenty of resources across Stack Overflow and on the web to learn about dependency injection and inversion of control patterns, but [Mark Seemann's blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Preston for your response. I will try your solution and read the blog. Once i am able to resolve my issues will mark the answer as correct